# How to store video files in SQL database using asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, video

I want to store the document, image and video to be stored in database. I stored document in var-char data type, image in image data type, and how to store the video files and in which data type.And how can I retrieve these document, image and video from database.

Comment: It's pretty common to just store the file names (incl path) to the videos and images.

Comment: You can store the Video in `VARBINARY` format in Sql Server. Refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/12576/upload-video-file-audio-file-and-image-file-in-sql-server-d.aspx

Comment: how to retrieve it from database.